# Add to cart not working Laravel and vue js?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

hi i am developing an ecomerce with laravel and vue. it succesffuly add product on cart but the value in the cart quantity remain 0 untill i refresh the page then its appear.i tried alot but now working.
message appears product added to cart but quantity not updates until refresh

laravel blade:

```
<li class="cart" id="cart">
          <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
          <span class="d-block" id="itemsCountVue">@{{itemsCount}}</span>
          <span class="d-none" id="itemsCountJquery"></span>
        </li>
```

Vue JS

```
<script>

  var details = new Vue({
    el: '#app1',
    data: {},
    methods: {
      addtocart(productid, quantity) {
        console.log(productid, quantity);
        var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById('attrform'));
        fd.append('productid', productid);
        fd.append('quantity', quantity);
        $.ajax({
          url: '{{route('user.cart.getproductdetails')}}',
          type: 'POST',
          data: fd,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          success: (data) => {
            console.log(data);

            if (data.status == 'productadded') {
              // console.log(data.product.cartattr);
              nav.products.push(data.product);
              nav.itemsCount = parseInt(nav.itemsCount) + parseInt(data.quantity);
              if ((nav.precartlen + nav.products.length) > 0) {
                nav.noproduct = false;
                nav.checkoutbtn = true;
              }
              // Fire toastr
              toastr["success"]("<strong>Success!</strong> Added to cart!");
            } else if (data.status == 'shortage') {
              toastr["error"]("<strong>Sorry!</strong> Vendor has "+ data.quantity +" items left for this product!");
            } else if (data.status == 'removed') {
              toastr["error"]("<strong>Sorry!</strong> Vendor has removed this product!");
            } else if (data.status == 'quantityincr') {
              $("#quantity"+data.product.cart_id).html('('+data.quantity+')');

              nav.itemsCount = parseInt(nav.itemsCount) + parseInt(data.product.quantity);
              toastr["success"]("<strong>Success!</strong> Added to cart!");
            }
          }
        });

      }

    }
  })
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The template contains:

```
<span class="d-block" id="itemsCountVue">@{{itemsCount}}</span>
```

itemsCount is not defined inside the vue data object, and it's not defined as a computed property either.

You could try:

```
el: '#app1',
data: {
    itemsCount: 0,
},
```

Then everywhere you're setting nav.itemsCount also set this.itemsCount